# How do I centre my navigation bar

Tags: css, navigation

I'm trying to centre my navigation bar in the middle of the page...

This is what I've got so far, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong

I've tried changing a few things, but I don't know whether I make the changes in the #menu or the #menu li

```
#menu li {

    float: left; 
    border: 2px solid white;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:80px;

}

#menu li a{



    font-family:Din;
    display: inline;
    padding: 1px 30px;
    font-size: 33px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;

}

#menu li a:hover{

    background: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 1px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;

}

#menu li a,
#menu li.active a{
    padding: 0px 30px;
    display:inline;

}

#menu li.active a{
    color: #fff;

}

#menu{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 70;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;

}
```

Comment: A demo would be pretty nice ;)

Answer (score 1):

use `display: inline-block;`

Try this demo

http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/jvgU2/

Answer (score -1):

Add this code to your CSS.
I have tested it.

```
#menu ul{
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
    width: 80%;
}
```